# applescript list of droppeditems not displaying properly

Tags: applescript

i have the following code:

```
on open theDroppedItems
    set PosixList to {}
    repeat with a from 1 to length of theDroppedItems
        set theCurrentDroppedItem to item a of theDroppedItems
        set PosixPath to convertPathToPOSIXString(theCurrentDroppedItem)
        copy PosixPath to the end of the PosixList
    end repeat
    display dialog convertListToString(PosixList, space)
end open

on convertPathToPOSIXString(thePath)
    tell application "System Events"
        try
            set thePath to path of disk item (thePath as string)
        on error
            set thePath to path of thePath
        end try
    end tell
    return POSIX path of thePath
end convertPathToPOSIXString

on convertListToString(theList, theDelimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    set theString to theList as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theString
end convertListToString
```

I expect it to allow me to drop a file onto the applescript (saved as an application) and display a list similar to `/Users/adam/a.txt /users/adam/b.txt` however, it gives me 2 dialog's, 1 with the path to the first file, then the second with the path to the second file.  What am i missing?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this shortened version is more along the lines of what you are looking for?

```
on open theDroppedItems
    set posixList to {}
    repeat with a from 1 to length of theDroppedItems
        set theCurrentDroppedItem to item a of theDroppedItems
        set posixPath to POSIX path of theCurrentDroppedItem
        set end of posixList to (posixPath & linefeed & linefeed)
    end repeat
    display dialog posixList as string
end open
```

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for -- thanks so much!